# tmux cannot work with ssh-agent

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, tmux

I use `keychain` to manage `ssh-agent`, and I add it into my `.zshrc`.

I have a ssh key with passphrase.

With the normal terminal, I can use `ssh` without call a `passphrase`.

But in tmux, it will ask me to input a passphrase for my ssh-key.

These are run in normal terminal.

```
➜  ~ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID; echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
14112
/var/folders/hh/mmb417c53xx84ykdycyqls100000gn/T//ssh- 
lyHqTWPT02HF/agent.14111
```

If running `ssh my.server.domin`, it can connect directly.

I run `tmux` in the same terminal and then

```
➜  ~ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID; echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
14112
/var/folders/hh/mmb417c53xx84ykdycyqls100000gn/T//ssh-lyHqTWPT02HF/agent.14111
```

If running `ssh my.server.domin`, it will ask me to input passphrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that I have a `alias` with ssh. `alias ssh=ssh-ident`.

If I unalias it, all things are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems because of stale environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK.

See http://blog.mcpolemic.com/2016/10/01/reconciling-tmux-and-ssh-agent-forwarding.html

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach is to update the environment variables using a `PROMPT_COMMAND` (`bash`) / `precmd` hook (`zsh`).

The relevant snippet is

```bash
if [ -n "${TMUX}" ]; then
    eval "$(tmux show-environment -s)"
fi
```

Sources:

- https://without-brains.net/2020/08/05/tmux-and-ssh-agent-forwarding/
- https://www.johntobin.ie/blog/updating_environment_variables_from_tmux/